# date object with millisecond precision when using snowflake connector

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake connector python library. I am trying to fetch the value for a field ex. AddDate.
In DB it shows like this: `2016-05-21 00:42:28.456`

but when I try to fetch this though select query it comes like this: `(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 21, 0, 42, 28),)`

the value for seconds is shown only as 28 but not 28.456.

How can we get the exact value of seconds in float/string?

Comment: what's the data type?

Comment: Can you get it as a String(varchar) from the warehouse and then convert to whatever desired data type you want ?